zfs import was hanging first and now gives an I/O error
I use two external hard disks. They were working fine but yesterday i connected a 4 different disks all at once and was doing lots of data transfers, and
* had to hard boot 4 or 5 times.
That is one possible cause of the problem.
then when I tried to import the pool on this zfs drive today, it just hung at the command with no disk activity. I killed the import process and tried to shut down and it kept waiting for zpool at the shutdown screen.
so I had to
* hard boot around 3 times again in the same way as it kept getting stuck.
* Weirdly while it was stuck it also gave me something like this at least once:
$ zpool import zfs-pool-bkup

Broadcast message from root@user (somewhere)
Warning communication lost with UPS

I don't know if it was because of my stopping the apcupsd service or because i was shutting it down forcefully at the shutdown screen, but the next time the import wasn't hanging but gave me this message instead:
cannot import I/O error Destroy and re-create the pool from a backup source

the import checking thing gives me this:
   pool: zfs-pool-bkup
     id: 17525112323039549654
  state: ONLINE
 action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier.
 config:

zfs-pool-bkup                                  ONLINE
  usb-Seagate_Expansion_HDD_ .......-0:0  ONLINE

i don't even know if there is data corruption or not.  i tried getting a list of all the txgs as that is suppoed to make it possible to rollback or something. but  the command sudo zdb -e -ul  gives me 32 blocks.
also the zfs import -nFX   takes forever.
I really hope this is some usb mixup issue. because my computer gets powered off improperly all the time. there was another thing that happened yesterday.
* I was transfering around 200 gb of data from an ntfs ssd connected to a nvme case, and the copying caused the computer to freeze. at around 40k files everytime. that is the reason i was hard booting. but i'm pretty sure that was the other drive and not this one.
ps: I need to save my data and revert to the good old filesystems of yore. I cant handle this complexity. maybe the tooling is yet to mature but im outta zfs after this.
